# Relationship between Probability and Probability Density

Tags: statistics, least-squares, maximum-likelihood

I am attempting to understand method of least square for regression. So, likelihood of parameter is defined as $$\mathcal L(\vec\theta)\stackrel{\text{def}}=\prod_{i=1}^mp_Y(\vec y^{(i)}|\vec x^{(i)};\vec\theta)$$

It seems like the squared cost function $\mathcal J_\text{sq}(\vec\theta)$ is derived from $\mathcal L(\vec\theta)$ in the following steps: $$\begin{align}\ln\mathcal L(\vec\theta)&=\ln\prod_{i=1}^mp_Y(\vec y^{(i)}|\vec x^{(i)};\vec\theta)\\&=\ln\prod_{i=1}^m\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac12(\frac{\vec y^{(i)}-\hat y_\theta^{(i)}}{\sigma})^2)\\&=\ln\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}-\frac1{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^m(\vec y^{(i)}-\hat y_\theta^{(i)})^2\end{align}$$$$\begin{align}&\because f(\cdot)=-\frac{\sigma^2}m((\cdot)-\ln\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}})\text{ is decreasing. }\\&\therefore\text{As }\mathcal J_\text{sq}(\vec\theta)=\frac1{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m(\vec y^{(i)}-\hat y_\theta^{(i)})^2\text{ decreases, }\mathcal L(\vec\theta)\text{ increases. }\end{align}$$
I understand every line in the derivation except the second line. Line 2 implies that $$p_Y(\vec y^{(i)}|\vec x^{(i)};\vec\theta)=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac12(\frac{\vec y^{(i)}-\hat y_\theta^{(i)}}{\sigma})^2)\tag{*}$$
because of normality assumption: $$\vec y^{(i)}|\vec x^{(i)};\vec\theta\sim\mathcal N(\hat y_\theta^{(i)},\sigma^2)$$
In (*), LHS is probability of event "$Y=\vec y^{(i)}$ given $X=\vec x^{(i)}$" parametrized by $\vec\theta$, while RHS is the probability density function (PDF) of $\vec y^{(i)}|\vec x^{(i)};\vec\theta$. LHS is a probability of continuous random variable $Y$ conditioned on $X$ parametrized by $\vec\theta$.

My confusion is:
Generally, given continuous random variable Y, $$p[Y≤y]=\int_0^yf_Y(y)dy$$

Isn't $Y$ continuous? How do we even find the probability of event "$Y=\vec y^{(i)}$ given $X=\vec x^{(i)}$" parametrized by $\vec\theta$? Why isn't RHS of (*) an integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You are using the incorrect analogy. What you are really asking on the LHS is *what is the probability the sample taken takes specifically the given values*. In other words, assuming $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are discrete you could write one term as
$$
\mathbb{P}[X_k=x_k] = f(x_k),
$$
and even in the case where $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ are continuous, you are looking for $f(x_k)$, not $F(x_k)$ as you are suggesting.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

LHS is not really a PMF, it is not really discrete. It is a product of finite number of terms, since your sample is a finite set, and each element of the sample contributes one term to the LHS.

However, each term is really a continuous probability since you are assuming every variable involved has normal distribution. As a result, you end up with a finite product of continuous terms, exactly as your RHS indicates.

Comment: I reckon I misused the term "PMF" in this question. I'll make some new edits in my question. Thanks for your prompt reminder!

Comment: @JazonLeung please see the updated answer

Comment: Oh, I think I'm mixing up cumulative distribution function and probability density function. Thanks a lot.